# How do you pass a std::array?

Tags: c++, c++11

I was trying out something simple like this:

```
template<class T>
array insertionSort(array<T> arr) {

    for (int index = 1; index < arr.size(); index++) {
        for (int insertion = index; insertion > 0 && array[insertion - 1] > array[insertion]; insertion--) {
            std::swap(array[insertion - 1], array[insertion]);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

void main() {
    array<int, 10> mine = { 1, 0, 2, 9, 3, 8, 4, 7, 5, 6 };

    array result = insertionSort<int>(mine);

    cin.get();
}
```

It seems as though array requires two type parameters (the `type` as well as the `size`), so how do I pass it to and from a function without knowing the size up front?

Comment: Make the size a template parameter, too! Admittedly, most of the time you'll be better off passing iterators and abstracting your algorithms from any concrete representation. For example, the above code should also work for `std::deque<T>`, `std::vector<T>`, etc.

Comment: `Make the size a template parameter`, duh! Thanks

Comment: Make the size as a template parameter like @DietmarKühl suggested but and use it in the first loop instead of arr.size().

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In general, you don't really want to pass containers around! The same algorithm which works for `std::array<T, N>` also works for other data structures, e.g., `std::vector<T>` or `std::deque<T>`. The C++ approach in that case is to pass iterator and to [slightly] adjust the algorithm:

```
template<typename BidrectionalIterator>
void insertionSort(BidirectionalIterator begin, BidirectionalIterator end) {
    for (BidirectionalIterator it(begin); it != end; ++it) {
        for (BidirectionalIterator insertion(it), tmp(insertion);
             begin != insertion && *--tmp > *insertion; --insertion) {
             std::swap(*tmp, *insertion);
        }
    }
}
```

(I didn't verify that the algorithm actually works but you get the idea).

Note that the algorithm deliberately sorts the sequence in-place! If you want to create a sorted copy, create the copy and sort that: this way you have the choice to do it in-place or not rather than being forced to use an approach which may require excessive memory (OK, when the sequence is large you surely don't want to use this algorithm but that's a separate question).

Comment: That's interesting. I'm learning a lot about from this simple question.

Comment: Yup this answer is definitely better, every function in the algorithms header takes iterators not containers

Comment: Using iterators also allows you to sort only part of the range if you want to.

Answer (score 10):

It works the same way as passing the object without knowing the *type* up front. You use a template parameter:

```
template<class T, size_t arrSize>
std::array<T, arrSize> insertionSort(std::array<T, arrSize> arr) {

    for (int index = 1; index < arrSize; index++) {
        for (int insertion = index; insertion > 0 && array[insertion - 1] > array[insertion]; insertion--) {
            std::swap(array[insertion - 1], array[insertion]);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

IMO, you should just pass the size as a template parameter and use it in the loop instead of arr.size():

```
template<class T, size_t size>
array<T, size> insertionSort(array<T> arr) {

    for (int index = 1; index < size; index++) {
        for (int insertion = index; insertion > 0 && array[insertion - 1] > array[insertion]; insertion--) {
            std::swap(array[insertion - 1], array[insertion]);
        }
    }

    return arr;
}

void main() {
    array<int, 10> mine; mine.fill(0);

    array<int, mine.size()> result = insertionSort<int, mine.size()>(mine);

    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `mine.size()` doesn't seem to work (because it isn't a constant value).

Comment: Then maybe a decl `const int arraySize = mine.size()`

Comment: @sircodesalot: It's more likely that your compiler doesn't implement `constexpr` correctly (or at all if it's Visual Studio). `array::size` is `constexpr`. So that should be legal. Though personally, you should just use `auto`. Or better yet, use `std::sort`, rather than copying the array around.

Comment: Yeah, visual studio seems behind the curve. What do you use?

Comment: @NicolBolas `auto` for what exactly?  from the code he posted, it seems that the only thing he could use `auto` for is the `result` variable.

Comment: @user9000: Yes, that's what I meant; `auto result = `. That way, he wouldn't have to type the same type again.